# How to detect if a binary number has a 0 in Decimal

Tags: assembly, binary, nasm

I have a binary number and I need to know if that binary number has a **0 anywhere** in the number when I represent it as Decimal.

So, I can't convert it to a String or something like that.

I need some way to treat it just like a binary and detect it from there.

for instance

```
10111100101 = 1509
101111001011 = 3019
```

I need to detect those 0

ThankS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only method I know is to partially convert the number to decimal, without remembering the results. Something like this:

```
; number is in eax
    mov  ecx, 10
loop:
    cdq
    div  ecx
    test edx, edx
    jnz  loop
    test eax, eax
    jnz  zero_found

; zero not found

    ret

zero_found:

    ret
```

Comment: Dynamic division is unnecessary here, since `10` is a constant.

Comment: What is "dynamic division"?

Comment: It's where the dividend is only known at runtime. If, by contrast, the dividend is known statically, you can multiply by the inverse, which is faster.

Comment: Faster for this task is not needed. Of course you can provide better answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way u can do it is by

1. converting your binary number to its decimal form
2. scan its bits for 0 via a counter
3. if zero found, do this, or else do that... depends upon you...

An appropriate code can be easily designed for that. :)